# Testing assigns with ActiveModel in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activemodel

Using Rspec 3.4, I've got a Message class:

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Model 
end
```

The following controller spec fails:

```
context "with invalid params" do
  it "assigns a newly created but unsaved message as @message" do
    post :create, { message: @invalid_attributes }
    expect(assigns(:message)).to be_a_new(Message)
```

The failure message is:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:message)).to be_a_new(Message)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `new_record?' for #<Message:0x00000006dc8a88>
```

So it looks like rspec calls `new_record?` when I call `be_a_new(Message)`, and since my Message class does not inherit from ActiveRecord I'm getting this error.

**How can I test that `assigns(:message)` is indeed a new instance of my Message class?**

I've tried the following:

```
# this works, but I don't like it
expect(assigns(:message).to_not be(nil) 

# these fail because the instances are not equal
expect(assigns(:message).to eq(Message.new)
expect(assigns(:message).to eql(Message.new)
expect(assigns(:message).to eqeul(Message.new)
expect(assigns(:message).to be(Message.new)
```

Is then a railsy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try following:

```
expect( assigns(:message) ).to be_kind_of Message
```